# Make a program in which the user introduces the lenght value of the radius or side of a shape, then selects a shape, which is drawn with said value?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, python-turtle

I need to make a program where the user enters the value that he wants the radius or side of the figure to have, and then chooses one figure from the possible ones from a list so that it is drawn with the previously entered value, and then the same with a second figure. For this I decided to use tkinter and turtle in python.

The problem is that when I want to store the value in a variable, I get this error: Entry.get() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Also, the code I use to trigger the `select` function and draw the circle, in this case, when that option is selected, `ComboboxSelected` doesn't seem to trigger anything. I don't know if I should put the option in another way inside the function. In this case, I imported turtle for drawing the figures, since it seemed less complex to me.

Obviously, the other figures still need to be programmed and the other list for the second figure, but I want it to work before continuing. All kind of advice is welcomed. Here is my code. Some parts are in spanish, but they are mostly the functions' and variable names and text displayed as titles, so I hope they dont become much of an obstacle.

```
from turtle import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

inicio = Tk()
inicio.geometry("600x500")
inicio.title("Dibujos de figuras")

texto = Entry(inicio, font = "Helvetica 15")
texto.place(relx=0, rely=0.1, relwidth=1, relheight=0.05)
m = None

radiolado = Label(inicio, text = "Radio o lado en cm")
radiolado.place(relx=0, rely=0.05)

def guardar_Valor():
    global m
    valor = Entry.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    m = valor

def select(event):
        if lista_1.get() == "Círculo":
            c = Turtle()
            c.circle(m)

figura_1 = Label(inicio, text = "Figura 1")
figura_1.place(relx=0.43,rely=0.25)

figura_2 = Label(inicio, text = "Figura 2")
figura_2.place(relx=0.43,rely=0.6)

lista_1 = ttk.Combobox(inicio, state="readonly",values=["Círculo", "Cuadrado", "Triángulo", "Pentágono", "Hexágono"])
lista_1.current(0)
lista_1.place(relx= 0.35,rely=0.3)
lista_1.bind("«ComboboxSelected»", select)

Boton1= Button(inicio, text = "Guardar", command = guardar_Valor)
Boton1.place(relx= 0.42,rely=0.18)


lista_2 = ttk.Combobox(inicio, state="readonly",values=["Círculo", "Cuadrado", "Triángulo", "Pentágono", "Hexágono"])
lista_2.current(1)
lista_2.place(relx= 0.35,rely=0.7)

    

inicio.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  What ```Entry``` value you are trying to get?   ```texto```?

Comment: You are calling `get` on the `Entry` _class_. You need to call it on an instance of `Entry` (eg: `texto.get(0, "end")`)

Comment: You should use `<<` and `>>` instead of `«` and `»` to specify virtual event: `<<ComboboxSelected>>`.

Comment: Hi ewong. Yes, that's right

Comment: Hey Bryan. I corrected it like you said, but the same error message appears. It even says 3 arguments were given.

Comment: I used the symbols you said, acw, and it did something, but now it says "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str". Should it be written like `lista_1[0]`?

Comment: You need to convert `m` to integer inside `select()` because `c.circle()` expects an integer but `m` is a string.